# R: Get column size using index

Tags: r

I'd like to get the size of a column using the index. I tried using the `length()` function with the column index inside, but it doesn't work:

```r
length(bd[7])
```

I'm sorry if this is too basic, I'm new to R. Thank you!

Comment: This post might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el

Answer (score 3):

The `bd[7]` is still a data.frame with single column and `length` for a data.frame is by default the number of columns.  We need to extract the column as a `vector` and then use `length`.  Extraction of column depends on the `class` i.e. if it is a data.frame/matrix, then `bd[,7]` would `drop` the dimensions and return a vector, but it is not the case with `data.table/tibble`.  However, all of them works with either `$` or `[[`

```
length(bd[[7]])
```

Or if it is a `data.frame` or `vector`, `NROW` would still work though

```
NROW(bd[7])
```

i.e.

```
> NROW(1:7)
[1] 7
> NROW(data.frame(col1 = 1:7))
[1] 7
```